# MercadoPago pasar parámetro por URL de pago

Tags: mercadopago

Recibo pedidos desde un ecommerce en un formulario de Google sheet. Luego el cliente va a una página de pago dónde están los links. MercadoPago para pagar su orden.

Sucede que luego no puedo vincular todos los pagos con las órdenes porque utlizan otros nombres o cuentas q los datos dejados en mi formulario.

Hay alguna manera de pasar algún parámetro como el nombre por URL en los links de pago de MercadoPago de modo tal q luego de pagar queden guardados en la ficha de venta en MercadoPago y así poder machear ambas bases?

Gracias

Comment: Haz visto las opciones de desarrollador de la página de MercadoPago?
Por ejemplo [aquí](https://www.mercadopago.com.pe/developers/es/guides/payments/button/create-button) te da la opción de generar un botón o link con lo que ellos dicen: "_Código de referencia para identificar la venta en tu backend._"

Comment: @erianvc no sirve ya que el código de referencia se configura a nivel del link y es un texto estático no dinámico y no se puede pasar por url. queda fijo para el botón. Qué otra sugerencia me podrías dar para que pueda pasar info por url de link de pago?

Comment: No hay ejemplo del codigo html del boton para que te podamos ayudar. pero creo que @erianvc tiene razón, el parámetro referencia, podrás cambiarlo con javascript. accediendo al formulario, sera un <input type='hidden'.  te recuerdo, que no he podido ver el código que te dan del botón, por lo que estoy imaginándome todo.

Comment: @ALBERTOPERALTA no es posible cambiar el parámetro referencia ya que no es parte del html o javascript del botón. lo de referencia se setea en el servidor n mercadopago pero no es "pasable" en el html del botón